# Mock RxHttpClient in MicronautTest

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mocking, spock, micronaut

I have this MicronautTest

```
@MicronautTest
class ApiTest extends Specification {

@Inject
@Client("/test/info")
RxHttpClient client = Mock()

@Inject
CapApi capApi

def "test should return info response"() {
    given:
    def mockInfoResponse = InfoResponse.builder()
            .ver("1.9.1")
            .build()
    client.retrieve(_, _) >> Flowable.just(mockInfoResponse)

    when:
    def result = capApi.retrieveInfo("/test/info")

    then:
    result.ver == "1.9.1"
}
}
```

and that is the tested class.

```
@Singleton
public class CapApi {
private final RxHttpClient client;

public CapApi(RxHttpClient client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Retryable
public InfoResponse retrieveInfo(String uri) {
    return client.retrieve(GET(uri).header("accept", "application/json"), InfoResponse.class)
            .blockingFirst();
}
}
```

no matter how hard I try... I am not able to mock the client of the CapApi class.
I also tried it with MockBean withoud success.

Comment: Can you show the code that you had with `@MockBean`? Your current example can't work. Furthermore, why do you need to mock the client instead of the service that is called by the client in the end?